# possible meaning of a constant

Tags: number-theory

I am sorry if the question is ambiguous. Is there any result closely related to the constant $\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$? It does not count if you say " it is a root of $x^2-x-1/4=0$".

Comment: You want a real world application that yields this result?

Comment: Yeah, that is also within my curiosity.

Comment: If that isn't the sole question, can you please rewrite it(not trying to be rude, but I can't interpret it any other way)

Answer (score 2):

This constant is half of the [Silver ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio), $1+\sqrt{2}$, which is analogous to the golden ratio.  European paper (A4, A5, etc.) is sized by the silver ratio, if you remove the largest square.

Comment: that is fun, I didn't notice that.